# Flutter Navigator 2.0 with Getx

Tags: flutter

I'm working on building web application with flutter web and have issue about forward buttons. I'm using `get` package for the navigation.

[image: Here is my code]

If I navigate to other pages and press the back button, the forward button should be able to click but It is enable whereas the back button works well.

Is there a method to fix this issue??

Comment: Please did you manage to correct your issue? If so, do share with us here.

Comment: Very basic requirement seems to be missing in Flutter web.